# While loop for rendering the star value on a review section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this loop to add a star value to a review section. It uses a custom data value to hold the amount of stars needed.

The "i" tag refers to Font Awesome.

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="reviewStars" data-starCount="5"></div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="reviewStars" data-starCount="4"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.owl-item div.reviewStars').each(function(){
    i = 0;
    while(i < $(this).attr('data-starCount')){
        $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-star">');
        i++
    };
});
```

This works well, but if the reviewer leaves 4.5 stars, I would like the last star to be this tag:

```
<i class="fa fa-star-half">
```

I'm not sure what the best way to accomplish this would be.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple addition you could make is to check the modulus of the number, if it is not 0, then (assuming the rating is either whole or half stars), there must be a half star given

```
$('.owl-item div.reviewStars').each(function(){
    i = 0;
    while(i < $(this).attr('data-starCount')){
        $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-star">');
        i++
    };

    // Check for and add a half star
    if ($(this).attr('data-starCount') % 1 !== 0) {
        $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-star-half">');
    }
});
```

I personally wouldn't build the stars up this way, however in the interests of simply answering your question, there you go :)

Comment: beat you by less than a minute. ;)

Comment: StackOverflow told me there was a comment, but I decided to post anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

You could do exactly what you're doing now. With 4.5, it should add 4 stars. After the while loop, do:

```
if ($(this).attr('data-starCount') % 1 !== 0) {
  $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-star-half">');
}
```

If the number % 1 doesn't equal zero, that means it is not a whole number. In that case, just add the half star. Also, you may want to store the attr in a variable so you don't have to keep locating it.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of working answers but keeping code readable and efficient is worthwhile. We don't need to create a jQuery wrapper around the element 6 times, and we can factor out the generation of the HTML from the append operation which makes it easier to read in my opinion

```
$('.owl-item div.reviewStars').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var star = '<i class="fa fa-star">';
  var halfStar = '<i class="fa fa-star-half">';
  var rating = $this.attr('data-starCount');

  while (rating-- > 0) {
      content += star;
  }
  if (rating >= 0.5) {
    content += halfStar;
  }

  $this.append(content);
});
```